# particles render black

Tags: rendering, particles

this is probably a simple thing but i just started using blender this week and made a particle system. the probleme i have now is that in material view the particles have the color they are supposed to but when i got to render view they are suddenly black. i've been looking around for the past 2 hours without finding anything and i've been trying to change settings i think it might be but nothing seems to work any help would be appreciated.

i'm using cycle render and there is also a spotlight shining straight on the particles

my material [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PzA2.png)

the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rixrbrM__1k&list=PLhGKy_BaZHMykpoe5GsW25WfKfCPmgMq_) i partialy used for the particles

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal (default renderer) or Cycles ? Could you provide a screenshot of your material settings and your scene ?

Comment: i'm using cucles as the tutorial said to do but if i change to the other ones nothing shows up in render anymore. as for my [settings](https://i.imgur.com/iubXzjr.png)

Comment: cycles sorry cant edit comment

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they appear as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)